# SwifityJSON problem with parsing JSON to ViewController from other libraries/frameworks

Tags: ios, json, swift, tableview, cell

I have the following json look like:

```
"message": "Something message here"
"data": [ 
  { "_id": "671672167bhw2hw"
    "photo": "https://uploads.example.com/671672167bhw2hw.jpg"
    "description": "Something description here"
    "date": "2020-07-01T09:44:15.448Z"
     "user": "John Doe"
  }
 ]
}
```

I used SwiftifyJSON library to decode and parsing JSON. My code is look like:

```
class Post: NSObject {
 var message: String
 var text: String?
 var photoURL: URL?
 var date: Date?
}

init(json: JSON) {
  self.user = User(id: json["user_id"].stringValue,
                         name: json["user"].stringValue,
                         photoURL: URL(string: json["user_photo"].stringValue))
  self.message = json["message"].stringValue
  self.objectId = json["data"]["_id"].stringValue
  self.text = json["data"]["description"].string
  self.date = DateFormatter.iso8601.date(from: json["data"]["date"].stringValue)
}
```

and my ApiManager extensions

```
 static func getPosts(before date: Date? = nil, withSuccess success: @escaping (Bool, [Post]) -> Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: ApiEndpoint.Wall.getPosts) else {
            success(false, [Post]())
            return
        }
        
        var json = [String: String]()
        
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            ApiManager.request(url: url, method: .post, parameters: json) { response, statusCode in
                switch statusCode {
                case 200:
                    success(true, ApiManager.getWallPostsFrom(response: response))
                    return
                    
                default: break
                }
                
                success(false, [Post]())
                return
            }
        }
    }
    
    private static func getPostsFrom(response: DataResponse<Any>) -> [Post] {
        var result = [Post]()
        
        guard let value = response.result.value,
            let jsonArray = JSON(value).array else { return result }
        
        for json in jsonArray {
            let object = Post(json: json)
            result.append(object)
        }
        
        return result
    }
    
}
```

I get response with 200, it's OK.
But still not working for displaying data in PostViewController. What is wrong? Additionaly I use my own libraries for tabs in application like Contacts, Messages, Discussion Panel and more, so I use my own library with some files, models, views, assets for any tab.

Below is my PostViewController for displaying data from JSON.

```
private func tryGetPosts() {
        canLoadPosts = false

        tableView.dataState = .downloading
         ApiManager.getPosts(before: Posts.last?.date) { [weak self] (success, objects) in
            self?.tableView.dataState = .noData
            
            print("Objects count: ", objects)

            guard objects.count > 0 else { return }

            #warning("Insert animation")
            self?.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self?.Posts += objects
            let indexPaths = (self!.Posts.count - objects.count ..< self!.Posts.count)
                .map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
            self?.tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .top)
            self?.tableView.endUpdates()
            self?.Posts.insert(contentsOf: objects, at: self?.Posts.count ?? 0)
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
            self?.canLoadWallPosts = true
        }
```

Please for any reply and advice.
Best regards.

Comment: Drop `SwiftyJSON` and use `Decodable`. Your handling of the dictionary keys looks very confusing. For example what is `JSON(value).array` supposed to point too.

Comment: the json you are getting is an array and the data you are trying to parse is on 0 index of that array, I can't see some key in your json also use json["_id"].stringValue instead of json["data"]["_id"].stringValue because data is not available here I guess, use print statement in your init mathod to be sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for this problem was in `JSON(value).array`.

If your JSON structure have like "data" array you can write `JSON(value)["data"].array`. SwiftyJSON is really friendly and easy library.